# How to list the allowed ip that can login mysql?

Tags: mysql

I know use the bellow commands, can allow a remote ip to login MySQL:

```
GRANT select，insert，update，delete ON *.* TO root@"my_ip" IDENTIFIED BY "my_password";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But how can I list the allowed IPs that can login the MySQL?

Comment: Careful: allowed to "connect" to a MySQL server are all clients able to setup a socket on network level, usually _all_ clients if the firewall allows connections to the port MySQL listens on. You probably refer to clients being able to login, not those being able to connect...

Comment: To find these grants present inside a MySQL server just look into the tables inside the internal "mysql" database. That is where the server stores the granted permissions. You can use standard SQL commands for that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

Will show you all users, and their allowed IP (ranges) in column **host**.

| User | Host |
| --- | --- |
| user_LAN_3 | 192.168.1.3 |
| user_DMZ_4 | 192.168.2.4 |
| user_DMZ_ALL | 192.68.2.% |
| user_LAN_DMZ_ALL | 192.168.% |
| please_dont_do_that | % |
| local_web_app | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session | localhost |
| mysql.sys | localhost |
| root | localhost |
| sysadmin | localhost |