# Why can't I log in to MySql in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have a webserver on an other computer using **xampp** to run **MySql**. I can log in using a browser to **ip/phpMyAdmin/** with the creditinals **root** and **password**. But I can't log in with C# using the **MySql.Data** library.

Code:

```
var connectionData = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

connectionData.Server = "ip";
connectionData.Database = "db-name";
connectionData.UserID = "root";
connectionData.Password = "password";
connectionData.Port = 3306;
connectionData.SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None;

var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionData.ToString());
connection.Open();
```

At `connection.Open();` I get the exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Authentication to host 'ip' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'my-ip' (using password: YES)'
```

What am I doing wrong here? The creditinals are the same, so it should work.

Comment: That error message is pretty clear: you were _**successful**_ creating a session with the MySql service, but were denied access because of a bad password or account name. You may need a host name instead of an ip. If it worked when you tested from the local machine for MySql, you may also need to change the mysql settings to allow remote connections. Finally, make sure you really are connecting to the same database.

Comment: first check the allowed ip that can login mysql for your user using :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629355/how-to-list-the-allowed-ip-that-can-login-mysql if the ip is not listed for the user then try to add the ip